# Python regex different in regex testers

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following regex:

```
((?:[^,\"']|\"(?:\\.|[^\"])*\"|'(?:\\.|[^'])*')+)
```

which when run against...

```
1266,206,'_xyz_xy','Abcde don\'t etc abc sdfkjhlsd, sdfkjhkehwc, sdfkjhwei kjhiensnfb.'
```

in an online tester gives me...

```
[1266,206,'_xyz_xy','Abcde don\'t etc abc sdfkjhlsd, sdfkjhkehwc, sdfkjhwei kjhiensnfb.']
```

but when I run it in my python script gives me...

```
['1266', '206', "'_xyz_xy'", "'Abcde don't etc abc sdfkjhlsd", ' sdfkjhkehwc', ' sdfkjhwei kjhiensnfb.']
```

I'm trying to split the string based on commas, but ignore commas that are within quotation marks (as per the tester string).

The regex tester and python seem to be treating the strings differently despite the face that the same regex is used (and I've switched to regex mode on the tester)

Can someone tell me why this is and how I can fix it?

**Edit:**
The code I'm using is:

```
result_items = re.findall("((?:[^,\"']|\"(?:\\.|[^\"])*\"|'(?:\\.|[^'])*')+)",input_string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Adding an r prefix also provides the same result

Comment: can you show us the code you're using

Comment: Define your input string and regex pattern with an `r` prefix (you seem to have lost literal backslashes in the output).

Comment: I've added in the r prefix, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything..
re.findall(r"((?:[^,\"']|\"(?:\\.|[^\"])*\"|'(?:\\.|[^'])*')+)",input_string, re.IGNORECASE)
Result: ['1266', '206', "'_xyz_xy'", "'Abcde don't etc abc sdfkjhlsd", ' sdfkjhkehwc', ' sdfkjhwei kjhiensnfb.']